# Cannot upload profile picture in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to upload profile picture for Django user but it does not work, the other field (website) is working just fine. I tried several solutions found here but I can't find any that worked for me. I don't know what is wrong, I'm just new to Django. I hope you can help me.

models.py

```
    class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        website = models.URLField(blank=True)
        picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.user.username

    User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

views.py

```
    @login_required
    def edit_profile(request):
        context = RequestContext(request)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = UserProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/rango/profile/')
        else:
            user = request.user
            profile = user.profile
            form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

        return render_to_response('rango/profile_registration.html', {'form':form}, context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set your MEDIA_ROOT in settings, something like this

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Also make sure that you created first the MEDIA_ROOT directory. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have those settings, I can upload pictures on the Django Admin...

Comment: Are you getting 404 not found error? By the way, you can access the photo in the template like this:
{{ profile.picture.url }}

Comment: No 404 error, I can view the image on the template when I uploaded it on Django Admin, but when it is uploaded via the views.py edit_profile() it doesn't work...

Comment: Can you try removing instance in the form under request.POST?

Answer (score 0):

Do you created a folder "media" in the root-path of your Django-project?

Here is some information about static files in Django: [Django-static-files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/)

In one of my projects I have the following entries in my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

And I also created both foldes in the projects root directory.

Otherwise if this does not work, pleas provide more information about your error-log.

Comment: Yes I have set those, I dont have any problems uploading photo on Django Admin. I just couldn't make it work on the front-end. Thanks!

Comment: How do you access the image in your template? It should be something like this: <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" height="420">

Comment: I can view the image just fine if the image is uploaded via Django Admin, the problem is the image won't upload if is on views.py edit_profile()

Answer (score 0):

Include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form where you want your users to upload picture.

```html
<form class=""  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{form.as_table}}
  <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
</form>
```

I also had the same requirement as yours and this helped.